# Owl Slider not working after AJAX Resposse

Tags: jquery, ajax, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Here, I have a page where Data changes by Ajax in <kbd>id="Products"</kbd>, But here Slider not work correctly. When data changes Slider Not working.

In Console, I'm getting this error. Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Also i have tried to put slider css and js in Ajax File. But still not working.
also looked many SO Questions but not found any perfect solution.

```
<div id="products">
        <div class="owl-carousel color-options">
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/1.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/2.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/3.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/4.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/5.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/1.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/2.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/3.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/4.png"></a></div>
            <div><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-full="image/2.png"><img src="image/5.png"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$('.color-options').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        items:4,
    })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `success:` function of the AJAX call, you have to reinitialize the Owl Slider.

```
success: function() {

    //Add success code here

    $('.color-options').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        items:4
    })
}
```

This forces Owl Slider to regenerate the slider from changed data.

Comment: this returns same error....  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).owlCarousel is not a function

Comment: Seems like owlSlider gets confused when the content is dynamic. Try modifying the slider dom dynamically (not with ajax) in runtime, and try to initialize owlSlider. In my opinion this issue has nothing to do with AJAX

Answer (score 0):

similar question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814426/uncaught-typeerror-owlcarousel-is-not-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516738/uncaught-typeerror-owlcarousel-is-not-a-function).
Are you sure you loaded the carousel plugin (js file)?.
Try moving it to the top of your scripts just after jquery lib.

```
<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
$('.color-options').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items:4,
})
</script>
```

Try destroying and re-initializing your carousel in your success function

```
owl = $('.color-options');

owl.data('owlCarousel').destroy();
  owl.owlCarousel({
     loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items:4,
  });
```

Comment: have already Included every require js and css, and working perfect Default. But facing problem when Data has been changed by AJAX. @sunny Chidi